# How to access AWS ElasticSearch Service automated snapshots/backups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I was under the impression AWS ElasticSearch service comes with automated snaphshots/backups. Thats what I find in the documentation. It suggests they happen once a day and are stored on s3 but I do not see any backups in any of my s3 buckets. How do you get access to the automated snapshots?

It probably doesn't matter but I used the following template to create my elasticsearch domain explicitly indicating I want automated backups.

**CloudFormation**

```
"SnapshotOptions": {
    "AutomatedSnapshotStartHour": "0"
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't get to the S3 bucket itself but you can restore from the backup stored inside it by using CURL or another HTTP client to communicate directly with your cluster telling it to rebuild from the "cs-automated" repository which is linked to the s3 snapshots. To be able to communicate with your ES cluster directly via HTTP you'll have to temporarily open an IP access policy to your cluster.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html#es-managedomains-snapshot-restore

Comment: That's an awful way to restore a snapshot.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac I've found no alternative. If you've found one post it.

Comment: I haven't either, but the technique you've posted worked well. Just to clarify, my criticism was directed at AWS, not your answer.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac I see. Yea that was my feeling when I was using it. Its an obsurd way to backup lol. Glad it worked for you. Cant believe they dont have a better option even now.

Comment: When you say " backup from it" do you mean "restore from it"? :) If so pls edit your answer.